# window.location only seems to work if I return false on the function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a javascript function being called by an input type="image" tag that generates a url and assigns it to window.location.

The problem is that unless I have a return false out of the function AND I actually break into the code and step to the return, it won't work.

So literally, if I let the code run, it refreshes the page but doesn't redirect to the new url (url has been verified correct).  But if I put a breakpoint in the javascript at window.location = 'url', and step to the "return false;" statement, it will work.

In firebug in NET, when it doesn't redirect, it shows the GET for that call spinning and never completing.

```
<input type="image" runat="server" id="btnFind" src="images/search.png" align="top" name="Go" onclick="ValidateAndRedirectSearchResults()"/>
```

I am setting runat to server because I am setting the src in the code behind as well as the
CausesValidation property to false.

Any suggestions?

```
  function ValidateAndRedirectSearchResults() {
        var text = document.getElementById('<%=someTextBox.ClientID %>').value;
        var url;
        if (ValidateSearchBoxContent(text)) {
            var criteria = ConvertStringToAscii(text);
            var tempUrl = document.getElementById('<%=tempUrl.ClientID %>').value;
            url = tempUrl + encodeURIComponent(criteria)
            //if I break here and step to return statement it works
            //I have tried window.location.href = url as well
            window.location = url; 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the source of `ValidateAndRedirectSearchResults()` ? Or at least the relevant parts that perform the redirection?

Comment: I have updated it with my code.

Comment: try putting an `alert(url);` before the `window.location` line. Make sure it's getting a validly formed url

Comment: @Bryan - I have, I put  (url has been verified correct) in my question because I verified this first.  I could take the url property value and paste in address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `onclick="return ValidateAndRedirectSearchResults()"` although this is a horrible way to attach event handlers. JavaScript belongs in `.js` files in the same way that CSS belongs in `.css` files

Comment: You are correct, except the project I am working in I can't push something like JQuery and bind (in this case Click()) to the control.

Comment: @pgtech, you can always use `document.getElementById(findButtonId).onclick = function (e) {...code...};`

Answer (score 1):

An "image" input is like a "submit" input. That's why returning `false` makes it work: it cancels the form submission.

You could also prevent the default action via the event itself.  (In fact I think returning `false` doesn't work necessarily in all browsers anyway.)

```
function ValidateAndRedirectSearchResults(ev) {
  ev = ev || window.event;
  if (ev.preventDefault)
    ev.preventDefault();
  else
    ev.returnValue = false; // IE

  // ...
}
```

(Make sure you bind the event handler in such a way as to ensure that the event is passed as a parameter in browsers where that makes sense.)